# How to set File Info from a script in Photoshop CS4

Tags: scripting, photoshop, cs4, fileinfo

I am developing a Photoshop CS4 script and want to set some of the File Info properties on the open document from within the script.

In other words, I want to do the equivalent of choosing File -> File Info and editing some properties, only via the scripting language (Javascript).

Comment: Wow, didn't know Photoshop had JavaScript extensions...

Comment: yep, you can automate pretty much anything with its scripting system (assuming you can work out what the properties and API's are).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have found it...

```
// Set copyright info
app.activeDocument.info.author = "Mr Blobby";
app.activeDocument.info.copyrighted = CopyrightedType.COPYRIGHTEDWORK;
app.activeDocument.info.copyrightNotice = "(c) 2009 Mr Blobby Ltd";
app.activeDocument.info.ownerUrl = "http://www.example.com/";
```

The docs are here...

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs4_javascript_ref.pdf